# Why do I get VM Exception while processing transaction: revert?

Tags: contract-development, web3js, truffle

I'm trying to call a function from a contract I've created on ganache-cli through a javascript on a website.

---

Here's the code of the java script:

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount=web3.eth.accounts[0];
var poe = web3.eth.contract(abi).at('0xc678e3c394db9408503195e506088803eef583b6');
console.log(poe.address);
poe.notarize2(result);
```

---

This results in a revert. However, when I execute the same function directly in truffle with the same values, no problem whatsoever.

---

Here's the contract code:

```
contract ProofOfExistence1 {

  mapping (bytes32 => bool) private proofs;
  // store a proof of existence in the contract state
  function storeProof(bytes32 proof) {
    proofs[proof] = true;
  }

  // calculate and store the proof for a document
  function notarize(string document) {
    var proof = proofFor(document);
    storeProof(proof);
  }

  function notarize2(string document) {
    bytes32 doc= stringToBytes32(document);
    storeProof(doc);
  }

  // helper function to get a document's sha256
  function proofFor(string document) constant returns (bytes32) {
    return sha256(document);
  }

  // check if a document has been notarized
  function checkDocument(string document) constant returns (bool) {
    var proof = stringToBytes32(document);
    return hasProof(proof);
  }

  // returns true if proof is stored
  function hasProof(bytes32 proof) constant returns(bool) {
    return proofs[proof];
  }

  function stringToBytes32(string memory source) constant returns (bytes32 result) {
    bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
    if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
        return 0x0;
    }

    assembly {
        result := mload(add(source, 32))
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Check if adding more gas make it work: `poe.notarize2(result, { gas: 2000000 });`.

Comment: HI, thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, that gets me the same result.

Comment: Your code seems to be ok. Are you using truffle? Some times truffle get confused with a corrupt artifact deleting `build/` folder and redeploying with `truffle migrate --reset` may make it work again. Also working with string is expensive try with a much larger gas value 4M, 6M. What does the transaction receipt says?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a migration?

I got the same error message and that's how I came across your question. Then I realized I forgot to add a migration and when I did, the problem was resolved. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but can you elaborate? I'm afraid I don't know what adding a migration means.

Comment: Hi, if you mean do a truff migrate -reset, yes, that worked!

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was to add the appropriate js file (e.g. 2_deploy_Contract.js) in the migrations folder. In case you have already done that, then --reset would have been my next suggestion, but @Ismael got it first. :)